# Lubunutu Does Not Know Where or How to Install Grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation, lubuntu

`The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/`

[image: Failure to Load Grub]

Without GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot.

Installation promptly crashed after this message.

There is no command line interface in which to start trying to install, fix or reinstall grub. It is as though no Linux was installed at all.

My problems started when my Lubuntu 16.01 was crashing during install and could not work out what to do about the swap.  It was as though the swap was being used and could not be allocated. I had accumulated too many problems with my repositories and it was time to start fresh.  Undeterred by the install problems, even after trying different combinations in many install attempts, I thought that if I reinstalled windows and linux and started with everything fresh, I might solve some problems.

[image: Partition Diagram]

I forced windows into 80 or so GB by leaving everything else unallocated and then booted Lubuntu usb and allocated 250 odd GB to my dual-boot-wide share (logical partition) then root (primary), home (logical) and swap (primary). I remember a time when I could see in the partition diagram the hierarchy of which logical partitions were a part of which primary partitions.  I don't really understand the model anymore.  I understood, in the past, I had only 3 or 4 primary partitions and I had to structure those into logical partitions.  But now, it looks like there isn't even a hierarchy and Windows doesn't even seem to say whether their bloody list of useless partitions are primary or logical.

Anyway, I want to install Lubuntu and I have not had one of these two days of halted productivity while i play with problematic installs since 2003.

What is confusing install?  Why doesn't it know where to put GRUB.  What is stopping it. Why can't it install grub, and why does the installer keep crashing for different reasons?

Thanks.  I'm absolutely stuck.  I think it has to do with all those windows partitions ms is forcing on me and conflicts with the MBR.

Comment: Where did you want to install Lubuntu (which partition)? GPT partitioning does no longer have 'primary' and 'extended' partitions, opposed to MBR.

Comment: there are two ext 4 partitions.   the first on the list is where what I was trying to set as /  the second, and larger of the two, was to be /home

Comment: the second photo was taken during the live session I am still in now.  the error, of course, was from during the install.  god knows why I didn't just use screen capture for the partition one..   :/

Comment: Oh yeah  :)  that's right.  they were 'extended partitions'  not 'logical'

Comment: /dev/sda1 to /dev/sda3 are windows' automatic partitions.
/dev/sda4 is the one I created and installed windows into
/dev/sda5 is my shared (logical) partition --  for storage
/dev/sda6 is /                (primary)
/dev/sda8 is /home    (logical)
/dev/sda7 is /swap       (primary,  I think)

Comment: I found some hints this could be a bug in the installer (see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub-installer/+bug/1521132). Some suggest to have internet connection while installing would help; I cannot check and so not help any further. Maybe  downloading latest installer and creating new installation medium might help.

Comment: thanks ridgy,  I have made three different usb drives with the freshest lubuntu.      if it is a bug I will just have to change distros  thanks.  I remember crunchbang was nice.  I might see if I can find an alternative to that lovely openbox incarnation.

Comment: Just tried again. I made sure there was an internet connection. I saw no alarm about grub but the installation still crashed.  It just can't make it to the end.  :(

Comment: tried with Ubuntu as well now.   I think they are struggling to get on top of the windows boot manager.  I think it is conflicting with how deal with the other efi

Comment: Have you tried: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair ? Recently installed Ubuntu on my very first UEFI box, couldn't manage to install grub with the same message displayed but thanks to it I've been using Ubuntu for a month.

Comment: Xangua --  ok, after some fiddling around, your tip on Boot-repair program sorted the issue out.  Thanks.  I am happy to be up and running again.  :)

Answer (score 1):

xangua  solved the problem by pointing me to boot-repair.   This is a bug.  the bug log suggests that people are trying to close it but it still appears to be causing problems.  Boot-repair fixed Grub and I was in business even though the installation never reported concluding on account of crashing.   Thank you, Xangua